# JavaScript - show followers from textfield

Tags: javascript

I want to display followers from twitter like here :

[image]

So, when i fill textfield with anything username
The result of followers will be displayed in bottom

This is my code :

- index.html

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
  <start twitter fan box –>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="twitterfanbox">
  <script type="text/javascript">fanbox_init("your_username");
  </script type="text">
  </start>
  </div id="twitterfanbox"> 
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- script.js

> function
>   fanbox_init(screen_name){document.getElementById('twitterfanbox').innerHTML=

```
    '\<iframe name=\"fbfanIFrame_0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowtransparency=\"true\"
src=\"http://s.moopz.com/connect.html?user='+screen_name+'\" class=\"FB_SERVER_IFRAME\" scrolling=\"no\" style=\"width: 300px; height: 250px; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-width: initial; border-color: initial; \"\>\<\/iframe\>';}
```

Comment: You don't need to escape your double quotes if you are using single quotes as your outermost quote type.

Comment: What doesn't work by the way? I don't see a form in your HTML code at all. What did you try?

Comment: it doesn't work when i fill textfield with anything username
it always display username in <script type="text/javascript">fanbox_init("your_username");

Comment: You are now always passing the string literal `"your_username"` into `fanbox_init`. Try `fanbox_init(prompt("what is your Twitter username?"))`.

Comment: @frank
Thanks a lot for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

You are now always passing the string literal "your_username" into fanbox_init: `fanbox_init("your_username")`.

Try `fanbox_init(prompt("what is your Twitter username?"))` - or as two statements:

```
var username = prompt("what is your Twitter username?");
fanbox_init(username);
```

This will display a prompt (a popup box that allows the user to enter a line of text) and passes that value to `fanbox_init`.